# Rails Active Record `group`: Why does this return only a few columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have this from a select statement in my Rails app:

```
...
 #<DailyStat subject: "Macroeconomics", topic: "Overview Of Economics", item_count: 160, correct_item_count: 0>,
 #<DailyStat subject: "Macroeconomics", topic: "Overview Of Economics", item_count: 1, correct_item_count: 0>,
 #<DailyStat subject: "Macroeconomics", topic: "Unemployment", item_count: 1, correct_item_count: 0>,
 #<DailyStat subject: "Macroeconomics", topic: "Inflation", item_count: 2, correct_item_count: 0>,...
```

I get this when I do a basic select of these columns. Now my problem is, when I do `daily_stats.select("subject, topic, sum(correct_item_count), sum(item_count)").group(:topic)` to aggregate the columns as to combine the item_counts and the correct_item_counts, the resultant result set is:

```
#<DailyStat topic: "Demand And Consumer Behavior">, #<DailyStat topic: "Obligations">, #<DailyStat topic: "Computerized Auditing">, #<DailyStat topic: "Inflation">, #<DailyStat topic: "Overview Of Economics">
```

I lose the counts. This must be just some sort of syntax issue, but I'm having trouble. How do I get the counts to add up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to include `subject` in your select clause, you also need to add it to the `group` clause.

```
daily_stats.select(
  "subject, topic, sum(correct_item_count), sum(item_count)"
).group('topic, subject')
```

When you execute this query you'd see the output as:

```
[#<DailyStat topic: "Demand And Consumer Behavior">, #<DailyStat topic: "Obligations">, #<DailyStat topic: "Computerized Auditing">, #<DailyStat topic: "Inflation">, #<DailyStat topic: "Overview Of Economics">]
```

The reason you don't see `sum(correct_item_count)` and `sum(item_count)` because they are not attributes of your model.

If you check the attributes of one of the objects within the result array you'll see the counts there, but without a key.  The keys will be empty.

Try:

```
daily_stats.select(
  "subject, topic, sum(correct_item_count), sum(item_count)"
).group('topic, subject').first.attributes
```

You could alias both your `sum(...)` for simplicity.  Something like follows:

```
daily_stats.select(
  "subject, topic, sum(correct_item_count) as total_correct_item_count, sum(item_count) as total_item_count"
).group('topic, subject')
```

This query will give you `total_correct_item_count` and `total_item_count` attributes on each of your resulting objects so you could access them as:

```
daily_stats.select(
  "subject, topic, sum(correct_item_count) as total_correct_item_count, sum(item_count) as total_item_count"
).group('topic, subject').first.total_correct_item_count
```

Comment: Thanks man! How do you extract the counts out, though. I have a follow up question. How would I then restructure the array into a [subject]=>[topic...]  though?

Comment: @DaryllSantos, apologies, not sure if I follow you. I would suggest you create a new question for the follow up question.  I think it's better to keep questions to one specific topic as much as possible.

Comment: Yes, you're right when it comes to separating the questions. I was going to ask about grouping the resulting rows by subject but I already solved it. Thank you so much for the answer, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Alias the counts. They'll become methods on the returned objects.

`foos = foos.select("count(name) AS name_count").group(:bar)`

`foos.first.name_count # => something`

Rails might use the column name that your DB makes when you don't alias a count, but if it did I wouldn't want to use it as a method name anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but even with the alias it still doesn't output the counts. `daily_stats.select("topic, count(correct_item_count) as foo").group(:topic)`